# Are serial upvotes detected?

Tags: discussion, voting

Based on a [**tweet from Jon**](http://twitter.com/jonskeet/status/8317560066)

Does the automated jerk detector also double as an automated nice-guy detector?  I was under the impression it just blew out serial-downvotes.

What all is caught by the system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should detect serial upvotes as well, to help prevent sock puppet accounts upvoting each other.

Have a look at [Vote Fraud and You](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/), apparently serial upvoting is actually a bigger problem than serial downvoting.

Comment: Ah, missed that one.  Came to the party a few months later than that.  I shoulda figured it would because of sock puppetry...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does look for up vote patterns as well.  How do I know?  It happen to me on Super User once.  Over a pattern of a few days, tons of my questions and answers got voted up back to back.  Within a few days, all the rep gained from the week disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it covers most all unusually patterned voting cases.