# Someone has done a run on me and I'm not sure what happens now

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, serial-voting

Someone has obviously taken a shine to me and voted me up to my reputation upvote cap of 200 in the last 15 seconds.

Clearly this is going to get caught by the system and pulled back out tonight. So my question is. If I continue to answer as normal and get up and downvotes etc. does the system only pull out reputation equal to that of the person who just upvoted a load of my stuff.

Meaning at the moment I am capped at 200 if I score another 200 in upvotes through normal means giving me a total of 400 (with 200 uncredited) when the -200 comes in later will it resolve the backlog of 200 to rep thus leaving me with a zero sum score?

Obviously bounties and accepted answers count differently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are serial upvotes detected?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37331/are-serial-upvotes-detected)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your reputation will be recalculated at the end of the day: The serial upvotes will be removed.

The later upvotes will give 10 additional reputation, provided that you haven't reached the rep cap yet (undone serial upvotes do not count towards this cap).

Comment: Reputation can also be manually recalculated on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @Tom - While true (for now)...it doesn't invoke serial voting detection, so it would still be done at the end of the day.